# Parsing WebClient SOAP response with extra stuff in body

Tags: web-services, soap, spring-webclient

I am trying to implement a reactive SOAP client using WebClient. My current implementation is based on https://github.com/gungor/spring-webclient-soap which uses `org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory` to parse the response body into a SOAP object. My problem is that the `createWebServiceMessage` method can't parse the response body since it has extra data in it:

```
--uuid:0afe4a46-8bdd-471e-b17f-0079c5bd2f4b
Content-Type: application/xop+xml; charset=UTF-8; type="text/xml"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <root.message@cxf.apache.org>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
...
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
--uuid:0afe4a46-8bdd-471e-b17f-0079c5bd2f4b
```

The error that is thrown is `Could not parse XML; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.`.

I understand that the uuid is some test thing and the rest is some "headers in body" thing but I don't understand how to configure `SaajSoapMessageFactory` (or any other `MessageFactory` so that it can parse the body. I have read every post on stack overflow regarding the uuid and the inline headers (and mtom) but I can't seem to apply it to my case.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. It looks like it might have something to do with MTOM-enabled SOAP responses - which allows the sending of binary attachment data: "By enabling MTOM, you can send and receive binary data optimally without incurring the cost of data encoding needed to embed the binary data in an XML document". I'm going to try figure out how to turn on MTOM for my Spring WebClient and see if that fixes things.